# How do I assign a string from an array to a variable in C (from a function)?

Tags: c

So, all I am trying to do is return a string from an array in a function to a variable in the main() function. Below is my function. It basically searches some files for a word, and returns the string name of the file that contains "START_ROOM":

```
char startPrompt()
{
    //array of files
    char* arrayFiles[7]={"Room1.txt", "Room2.txt", "Room3.txt", "Room4.txt", "Room5.txt", "Room6.txt", "Room7.txt"};
    //used to store file that has START_FILE in it
    char startFile;
    int i;
            for(i=0;i<7;i++)
            {
                    //pointer to files
                    FILE *fPointer;
                    //prints files to output
                    char loadScreenOutput[800];
                    char* response[256];


                    fPointer=fopen(arrayFiles[i], "r");
                    //checks if the file doesn't exist
                    if(fPointer== NULL)
                    {
                            printf("Unable to open the file!\n");
                    }
                    //if file exists, do this.
                    else
                    {
                            while(!feof(fPointer))
                            {

                                    fgets(loadScreenOutput, 800, fPointer);
                                    if(strstr(loadScreenOutput, "START_ROOM"))
                                    {
                                            return *arrayFiles[i];
                                    }
                            }

                            fclose(fPointer);
                    }
            }
```

The main function is here:

```
int main()
{
    char fileName;
    //start the game with the start file
    fileName=startPrompt();
    printf("%s", fileName)



    return 0;
}
```

Yet, the above leads to a segmentation fault.

If I change the printf to printf("%c", fileName), I will get the first letter of the file, which will be "R".

So, how can I simply get it to return "Room1.txt" and store it in fileName? I am willing to change the variable type of fileName, as I can guess that may be the issue. Or change the return type of the function, as I am guessing that is the issue.

Overwise, I know this code works because if I printf() inside the function, it will print "Room7.txt".

Comment: Why is the `while` loop there? `while(j!=1)` only loops once because of the `j=1;` at the end of the loop.

Comment: @InternetAussie , I deleted it. I guess the loop wasn't needed. Sorry, left over from something I was previously doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is a bit weird, but the main issue is that you expect a single character (i.e. `char`) to hold a "string", i.e. a sequence of characters. Strings in C are a sequence of characters terminated by special value `0`; they are often used with pointers to string literals, written as `char* someStringValue = "ABC"`:

```
char* str = "ABC";  // str will point to a sequence of characters {'A','B','C',0 }
char c = 'X'; // c will hold a single character 'X';
printf("%s",str); // will print ABC
printf("%s",c); // will probably segfault because c is not a pointer to a sequence of characters, i.e. is NOT A POINTER
printf("%c",c); // prints X
c = *str; // assignes the first character of the sequence to which str points
printf("%c",c); // prints A
```

To correct your program, write:

```
char* startPrompt()  // char* instead of char; char would be a single character
{
    // static; otherwise the variable and its values go out of scope and become invalid once startPrompt has finished
    static char* arrayFiles[7]={"Room1.txt", "Room2.txt", "Room3.txt", "Room4.txt", "Room5.txt", "Room6.txt", "Room7.txt"};
...
    return arrayFiles[i];  // not *arrayFiles[i], which would be a single character

...

int main() {
    char* fileName;  // char*, not char
    fileName=startPrompt();
    printf("%s", fileName)
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This answers the question. Thanks. Also, would it be better to possibly take in the variable instead a return? And assigning it in the function itself? I was considering that as well. aka "startPrompt(fileName)"?

Comment: If you have a set of predefined filenames, storing them in a static array of string literals and returning one of them (just as you do) seems a proper solution to me.

Answer (score 0):

A string is actually an array of chars (which is also a pointer to a contiguous group of chars in memory). You need to make the function return a pointer to the first char in you array. Also "*" is not needed in the char array declaration (doing that creates a pointer to the pointer to the first char in the array).

Comment: If I take away the "*" in arraFiles, it leads to an error: "filetest.c:17: error: excess elements in char array initializer
filetest.c:17: error: (near initialization for ‘arrayFiles’)
"

Comment: You mean the array of string `arrayFiles`? The `*` is  needed there so it reads as "an array of 7 pointers to char"

Comment: Neither a string nor an array is a "pointer to a contiguous group of chars in memory."